# How can I convert a wireguard vpn config file to openvpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I have a working vpn connection but it's imported in WireGuard and I need to use that same config on a OpenVPN client and import it there . Is there anyway to convert wireguard `.conf` files into `.ovpn` file and use it on OpenVPN client ?

Comment: You cant. You just have to write or create a new config for your openvpn server.

Comment: wireguard does not have the same features as openvpn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this, WireGuard is not OpenVPN, OpenVPN is not WireGuard they are different things that are only related by being VPNs.